Is it possible to keep React Context alive when moving between pages cached with Next.js Router Cache
I am using Next.js 14 with the app router. I have two routes, /businesses and /people. Both have a top-level React Server Component Page which fetches the respective list data for each page. Each Page then renders a client side component Content, which takes the list data and hydrates a React Context for that page with the data, called DataContext with its respective provider DataProvider.
// app/people/page.tsx
const Page = () => {
  const people = getPeople();

  return <Content entities={people} />;
};

// app/people/content.tsx
const Content = ({ entities }) => {
  const sortAndFilter = useSortAndFilter();
  const { filters, pagination, sort } = sortAndFilter;
  const searchableFields = ['name', 'role', 'businessName'];
  const data = useFilteredEntities({ filters, pagination, sort, entities, searchableFields })

  return (
    <SortAndFilterProvider value={sortAndFilter}>
      <DataProvider value={data}>
        <SearchPage />
      </DataProvider>
    </SortAndFilterProvider>
  )
};

I have verified the default 30 second client side Router Cache works by both logging on the server and looking at the network tab when moving between routes.
It appears that the React Context is being destroyed and re-created when navigating back to /people, as the list momentarily flashes in an empty state when navigating back to this page. This happens even though the page itself appears to be fully cached on the client side. I am wondering if it is possible to keep the React Context alive inside of the Router Cache somehow?


perhaps if you use next.js built in middleware https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware and extend client side caching by  modifing headers into longer then 30s time spams;
as for keeping React Context alive in the browser cache if the option above dosent work you can store the data in localstorage or cookies but the whole point of using client side state (like React Context) is that you can control and reflect in UI any changes to that state, by 'freezing' it in cache (or local storage) all those benefits are gone.

